# Dynamic canvas content to fit to canvas in c# on clicking of fit to screen button in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, screen

I have a canvas which is in `scrollviewer`. This canvas is a dynamic canvas on which many other controls can be dropped. The scrollviewer will be shown when controls are dragged & dropped out of canvas regions ie., right and bottom.

I have implemented the code for zoom in and zoom out of the canvas which works fine, but failed to find the code to implement fitting dynamic canvas content to the actual canvas size.

I'm looking for something to automatically fit the canvas content to its size, ie calculate the zoomscale as to fit the content to the canvas size.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complicated one.
You should work with some properties of the ScrollViewer to get the desired result: **ContentHorizontalOffset, ContentVerticalOffset, ViewportWidth, ViewportHeight (among others existing in the component..)**

Here is a snippet of code that helped me:

```
        Point realSize = new Point(this.canvasAreas.ActualHeight, this.canvasAreas.ActualWidth);
        Point sizeAvailable = new Point(this.scroolMain.ActualHeight, this.scroolMain.ActualWidth);

        double scaleX = sizeAvailable.X / realSize.X;
        double scaleY = sizeAvailable.Y / realSize.Y;

        double newScale = Math.Round(Math.Min(scaleX, scaleY), 2);

        this.gridScaleZoom.ScaleX = newScale;
        this.gridScaleZoom.ScaleY = newScale;
```

There are several articles on CodeProject and looking on google that can assist you in working with ScrollViewer zoom.
Although most are complicated and complex. Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: I have tried this code before.It was applying the scale on every click of fittoscreen button. Actually it should fit to the screen however many clicks performed, instead the controls on canvas are are becoming smaller since the scaling is being applied everytime.I have tried many articles but I haven't found the solution to find out the scale factor for dynamic canvas.

Comment: my code, if used properly, will have the result of the scale X and Y, to show all the component without scrolling (fittoscreen). I could not understand your problem, you can post some code snippet or explain better?

Comment: Hi,Here is my xaml code :                                                                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <forms:FormDesignerCanvas Grid.Column="2" x:Name="formCanvas" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Focusable="True" AllowDrop="True" Background="White" >
                    <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="canvasScale"
                            ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />

Answer (score 0):

Here is my xaml code:

and on Button click I would like to scale accordingly.I have tried the below code.

```
         Point realSize = new Point(this.formCanvas.ActualHeight, this.formCanvas.ActualWidth);
        Point sizeAvailable = new Point(this.myScrollViewer.ActualHeight, this.myScrollViewer.ActualWidth);

        double scaleX = sizeAvailable.X / realSize.X;
        double scaleY = sizeAvailable.Y / realSize.Y;

        double newScale = Math.Round(Math.Min(scaleX, scaleY), 2);

        this.canvasScale.ScaleX = newScale;
        this.canvasScale.ScaleY = newScale;
```

It also results the same.
Please correct the code if it is incorrect.

Comment: I have tried with the above code.But the problem is that I would like to show the canvas to fit to the screen how many clicks if i perform.If the canvas is loading with as much of controls it should scale accordingly either shrink or grow the canvas. Correct my code if it is incorrect.